# How to detect 'useless' click in HTML5 video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I need to detect only the clicks that don't fire any action. See example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/SdNL5/1/

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" controls>
     <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.onclick = function(){
    alert("This click is useless");
};
```

In that case when the user clicks the video he receives an alert message. BUT, problem is, I don't want the alert message to show up when the user clicks play button, pause button or volume control. I want it to show up only when the user clicks the video but not any button. Also I need to open a popup window after that so, I can't use setTimeout or similar in order for the browsers not to block the popup.

I'm aware that I can read coordinates and calculate whether there is a button or not, but I would prefer another solution.

Comment: Can you clarify? Double click on video isn't specified in your spec and performs an action (full screen, at least on my browser)

Comment: Then I add to my arbitrary spec: When double clicking, the first click does not perform an action, so it is considered an 'useless' click. I don't see how it makes a difference, though.

Comment: Browser implementations of controls vary - some clicks on the video actually act as controls. What about those?

Comment: it would be simpler and more compat to put a clear click-catching div over the video viewport. problem for you is that click() fires before pause() and all that, so you need a timeout if you're to have any hope of doing it with an event on the <video>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a question which is very similar to this one.([How to prevent event bubbling when clicking on HTML5 video controls in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916437/how-to-prevent-event-bubbling-when-clicking-on-html5-video-controls-in-firefox))

The only way I know to do that consistently in different browsers is to have an overlay over the video and then custom controls over that overlay.
There are several reasons why. For example 'useless' clicks will depend on the browser:

- Firefox will toggle play/pause when clicking on the video.
- IE will have a 'useless' click but on double click will go into
  full-screen.
- Chrome & Safari will have 'useless' clicks

BUT if you don't care about Firefox then this example would work for you but only in Chrome, Safari & IE : http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/cSTGM/40/

```
<a href="javascript: alert('Nothing');">
   <video ...
   </video>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

in this example im using setTimeout to let `.paused`, `.volume` And `.muted` to Be updated **before** I compare them with the last status (in the Variables).

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");

var isPaused = video.paused;
var lastVolume = video.volume;
var isMute = video.muted;

video.onclick = function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
                    // if the user did not change: Play/Pause && Volume && mute
                    if(isPaused == video.paused && lastVolume == video.volume && isMute == video.muted) {
                        alert("This click is useless");
                    } else {
                        // if the user did change, update to current status
                        isPaused = video.paused;
                        lastVolume = video.volume;
                        isMute = video.muted;
                    }
                }, 100);
}
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SdNL5/22/**

note: if the user click on volume control and did not make change, It will be considered as 'useless' click.

Comment: Unfortunately, as it is specified in the question, setTimeout is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

i know you already checked an answer, but please consider that you can still **hide the default video controls** and use your **custom controls** to play with.

if you don't want/have time to spend on it yourself you can just use some javascript lib like [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/)

> this way you'll have really full control both over buttons and video separately in a cross-browser way.

- http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh924822(v=vs.85).aspx